# Why do state's class variable are often done as private in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Why do state's class variable are often done as private? What are the cases when using public variables is bad for state classes? Who is going to use variable from state class like this: `_SplashState.storage`?

```
class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  var_storage = Storage(); // it could be public
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to create the `State` as private but it makes sense. The `State` class should be private indicating it should not be created anywhere outside `createState` override, as you are not creating/managing `State` object instance at all.

We can also say that it's good practice to declare a variable as private which is not to be accessed outside of the scrop.

Answer (score 0):

Private fields have the advantage that Lint can identify which fields were declared or instantiated and not used, which helps identify human errors.

If you declare a public field, the field can be accessed by outside classes, so Lint cannot warn you if you added the field by mistake.

Comment: The only advatnage?

Comment: No, other advantages too. Like if you accidentally created a class method with the same name as another `mixin` method and later on wanted to use the `mixin` but then suddenly discovered the method names clash and now you have to change it.